# Screeps - how to withdraw from multiple containers, and mine from multiple sources at once?

Tags: javascript, screeps

My code for miner:

```
const roleMiner = {
run: function(creep) {
    if (creep.carry.energy < creep.carryCapacity) {
        const sources = creep.room.find(FIND_SOURCES_ACTIVE);
        if (creep.harvest(sources[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
            creep.moveTo(sources[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffaa00'}});
            
        }
    } else {
       const containers = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {filter: (s) => (s.structureType == STRUCTURE_CONTAINER && s.store.energy< s.storeCapacity)}); 
        if (containers != undefined){
            creep.moveTo(containers[0]);
            creep.transfer(containers[0], RESOURCE_ENERGY) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE
                
             }
        }
    }
 };

 module.exports = roleMiner;
```

and my transporter code:

```
const roleTransporter = {

run: function(creep) {
    if (creep.carry.energy == 0) {
        const containers = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {filter: (s) => (s.structureType == STRUCTURE_CONTAINER && s.store.energy <= s.storeCapacity)}); 
        if (creep.withdraw(containers[1], RESOURCE_ENERGY) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
            creep.moveTo(containers, {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffaa00'}});
    }
} else {
        const targets = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {
                filter: (structure) => {
                    return (structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_EXTENSION ||
                            structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_SPAWN ||
                            structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_TOWER) && structure.energy < structure.energyCapacity;
                }
        });
        if (targets.length > 0) {
            if (creep.transfer(targets[0], RESOURCE_ENERGY) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                creep.moveTo(targets[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffffff'}});
            }
        }
    }
 }
 };
 module.exports = roleTransporter;
```

The point is, where I have container[0] or sources[0], the number is the container or source object.

How can I get a miner to harvest multiple sources at once, because I have 2 sources, and transporters to withdraw from multiple containers at once.

Comment: Maybe I got this completely wrong... or you want to use multiple sources at the same time (not the same creeps)... for this you better use something like `if(creep.transfer(creep.pos.FindClosestByRange(targets), RESOURCE.....` this way a creep will use the closes one (to that creep)...

Answer (score 2):

A creep can only perform one action of the same type each tick. If your creep perform withdraw twice, only the last of those calls will be evaluated by the server. It is technically the same with move. You can only move once per tick and it is only the last call to move that will go through to the server.

When your code makes a call to withdraw and the method returns OK it doesn't mean the action was performed. It means that the action was successfully registered as an "intent". A creep can register only one intent for each action. When your code has finished execution, these intents are sent to the server for evaluation. If you have a container with 100 energy and two creeps try to withdraw this energy, both creeps will get OK in response, but when the server executes your intents, only one of them will actually be performed.

Another thing to remember is the simultaneous execution rules. A creep can perform both a harvest and a move in the same tick, but if it tries to do both build and repair, only build will be performed.

More about this here:
http://docs.screeps.com/simultaneous-actions.html

Answer (score 2):

Some people use a simple random selection of all of the available sources. This is simple, but not preferable. What I do is, when a creep is ready to harvest, I use an algorithm to select a source and save the source ID to the creep's memory.

The algorithm I use to select the source takes into account the number of other creeps that are already targeting that source, the distance to the source, and the number of adjacent squares not blocked (by things like walls).

```
var source;

if (creep.memory.sourceId) {
    source = Game.getObjectById(creep.memory.sourceId);
} else {
    //Find all active sources
    //Count the number of creeps targeting that source
    //Count the accessible adjacent squares using something like room.lookForAt(...)
    //source = ... the source you selected
}

if (creep.harvest(source) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
        creep.moveTo(source, {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffaa00'}});
}
```

Something similar can be done for the transporters as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible at all. Although not [specifically stated](http://docs.screeps.com/simultaneous-actions.html#Additionally), I think it is the same case as with `transfer`:

> While `transfer` may `work` along with drop, you cannot execute `transfer` two and more times per tick (to transfer energy to multiple objects). The same is true for all similar methods.